# Jetpack Compose Custom UI - Speedometer with animation

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, custom-ui

I want to build a custom ui to show the score in a custom view like a speedometer with an animation. Implementation would be like passing a score to the view and the needle in the view is going to animate from 0 to the score passed. The background will change according to the score passed if less than 50 its red and above 50 its red.Can anyone help me achieving this.I am attaching the ui given for reference. It could shared to social media in any format also.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In summary will need to implement this component using `Canvas`.

I did an initial implementation which can give you a kick-off.

Here's the repository:
https://github.com/nglauber/JetpackComposePlayground/blob/master/app/src/main/java/br/com/nglauber/jetpackcomposeplayground/screens/SpeedometerScreen.kt

Here is the result:

[image]

Comment: Perfect implementation. I am having a small question how to change color of the arc on running like till 35 red,till 50 orange,100 to green.

Comment: Before the part commented as "Drawing Center Arc progress" you should replace the `mainColor` by the color in according to your logic.

Comment: I updated the code. Please, check it out.

Comment: Can i take a screen shot of this composable programatically and share to other apps?

Comment: Yes. Check this article: https://labs.testbook.com/how-to-share-composable-as-bitmap-e207c2f299d4

Comment: How can i reduce the height of the marker lines @nglauber

Comment: How can i rotate the upper line markers. so that the exact 50 will come to centre of the view. In the gif you attached we can see that the centre of view is a short line..logically it should be 50 and it should be a long as u set %5==0 in if condition. So how to fix this please help

Comment: can you please add comments in your implementation please